# Problems with pages module and page url

Tags: url, pages

At the moment I'm strugling with the pages module and the page uri. I have the following page created with the pages module:

```
members
 |- members/calendar
 |- members/safety
```

When I visit the URL `www.mypage.com/members` I will see the correct page.

When I visit the URL `www.mypage.com/members/calendar`, I will see the correct page.

But when I visit the URL `www.mypage.com/members/calendar/2013-12`, the `/members` page is shown.

But I need the calendar page and the last segment is a kind of variable. I use the Low Events calandar on the calandar page. Strict URL is "off".

If I put a question mark in the url `www.mypage.com/members/calendar/?2013-12` the calandar is shown, but now there is no `segment_3` that I can use in selecting the month in the low events calendar.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: I fixed my issue by enabling php en getting the month as a parameter. Don't think that this should be the way to do this, so I will keep the question open for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the [Template Routes](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/template-routes) add-on was made for. In your EE config.php, add your template routes config:

```
$config['template_routes'] = array(
  ':page:XX/(\d{4}-\d{2})' => 'site/member-calendar',
);
```

where XX is the entry_id of the members/calendar entry and 'site/member-calendar' is the template_group/template_name of your template.

Comment: Great add-on! Thank Rob, I could fix it with this add-on without the need of enabling php en create "ugly" URL's.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want the page content to be dynamic and not static the proper way to do this would be via the regular ExpressionEngine group/template/entry url parsing structure.

The Pages module is really for making "static" content. It looks for specific URLs and will not look for partial URLs then take the remainder as parameters - this is what the normal URL parsing is for.

Why are you using it in preference for the "normal" method in this case?

Because there is no Pages URL for /members/calendar/2013-12 the system defaults back to regular URL parsing which is why you get the members page.